# font color html inside tag don't change

Tags: html, css

I have a css what describe the h6 tag like this

```
h6{
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0f7f7f7;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
```

In just 1 line in my page I want an exception so I did this:

```
<h6 font color="red">text here not in red <br>
```

But I can't find why it still keeps the color, what is defined in the CSS

Comment: #0f7f7f7? wrong color code

Comment: you have an extra character in the color value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/z84q6bor/2/)**

**Option 1 :** in case you have one element you want to style :

```
<h6 style="color:red">text here is in red </h6>
```

*first of all*, `color: #0f7f7f7;` is not correct. all colors have 6 characters not 7 for their HEX value

*second*, you are missing the closing tag in the `<h6>` you always need to close it with `</h6>`

*third*, `color` attribute you use it like so

```
<font color="red">text here is in red</font>
```

*fourth* , the color attribute is not supported in HTML5. so  in html if you need to change smth use `style=""` . `<tagname style="property value">`

```
<h6 style="color:red;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase"</h6>
```

etc.

**Option 2** : if you have many items to which you want to apply same styling for example you want to add `color:red` to more elements, it's better **NOT** to use inline styling, but to add a class to those elements and then style them from CSS.

for eg

```
<h6 class="red">text here is in red</h6>
<p> some text</p>
<h2 class="red">text here is in red</h2>
<p> some text</p>
<h3 class="red">text here is in red</h3>
<p> some text</p>
```

and CSS

```
.red { color:red;}
```

for more information **click here [HTML style](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp)**

Answer (score 3):

Inline css looks like this

```
  <h6 style="color:red">text here IS red </h6><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your html is invalid. Here's how you do it.

```css
h6{
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
   <h6 style="color:red">text here is in red</h6>
```

Have a read about inline-css and the `style` attribute [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style).

EDIT: Seems like you have an invalid hex-value for your color.

Answer (score 0):

I think is just a matter of syntax. Try with:

```
<h6 style="color:red">text here not in red <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have the wrong syntax for applying inline styles. (As posted by @grateful)

Second you maybe better set a class name and apply styles to this class name. For example:

CSS:

```
h6 {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0f7f7f7;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

h6.important-note {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h6>A normal heading of size six.</h6>

<h6 class="important-note">A really important heading of size six.</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use:

```
  <h6 style="color:#ff0000">text here IS red </h6>
```